# Project creation error(Flutter create command was unsuccessful) while creating a new flutter project in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Whenever I try to create a flutter project in Android Studio I keep getting
***Project creation error.
Flutter create command was unsuccessful*** error.
It does generate and populate the files though.

Here is the output for 'flutter doctor'

```
> F:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4046], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.19.2 on channel stable at F:\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7482962148 (7 days ago), 2024-02-27 16:51:22 -0500
    • Engine revision 04817c99c9
    • Dart version 3.3.0
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at F:\androidsdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: F:\Android\android studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at F:\Android\android studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4046]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 122.0.6261.95
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 122.0.2365.66

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category
```

.

It has been many tries but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please show us the error?

Comment: Seems like there is no plugin added to Android studio for Flutter and dart. as per the flutter doctor output. Please install that first for android studio

Comment: @J.S.  When I create a new flutter project from FILES> NEW FLUTTER PROJECT It is just gives a pop up that says Project creation error. Flutter create command was unsuccessful. Where can I find more info?

Comment: @HardikMehta the plugins are installed... That I can confirm.